# Is flipping a coin following an omen?

Tags: halacha, money, sorcery-magic-kishuf, statistics, parashas-kedoshim

If a person is deciding whether to do something and says "I'll flip a coin, heads I do it, tails I don't" does that fall under the prohibition of "don't divine with signs" in Vayikra 19?

Answer (score 13):

[Chicago Community Kollel - Parsha Encounters 4 Shevat 5768](http://www.cckollel.org/parsha_encounters/5768/bo.pdf) in the name of Rabbi Yisrael Belsky Shlita, says that one may flip a coin to make a decision.

> When one flips a coin and makes a decision based on the results, he
>   does not feel his decision is necessarily the right thing to do.
>   Rather, he was undecided, and he is leaving his decision up to
>   "chance"

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question to R' Shlomo Shlezinger Z"l and his answer was:

> The very idea of Avodah Zarah assumes that some Earthy bodies or forces have a certain independence from G-d, have strengths of their own. So one who says "this dice has divine powers to guide me through my life" is an idolater.
>
> But one who follows Moses' "וְעַתָּה אִם נָא מָצָאתִי חֵן בְּעֵינֶיךָ הוֹדִעֵנִי נָא אֶת דְּרָכֶךָ וְאֵדָעֲךָ" and asks **from G-d** to show His will in throwing dice, that would surely be allowed.

Comment: Can't that logic also be extended to drawing lots and following omens [which appears to be forbidden]? One can simply claim "I'm asking from G-d to show His will through X" where X is {lots,omens,etc.}?

Comment: See the beginning of Rambam's Hilchos Avodah Zarah - it became AZ when people disconnected the bodies and forces as being G-d's servants from G-d and attributed independent capabilities to them. As long as a person holds that whatever happens comes exclusively from G-d's will it is permitted (in this view).

Comment: That seems to me like a too permissive approach. What prevents one from also applying it to, say, sorcery (which is clearly forbidden) and claiming that "it is just G-d showing His will"  through whatever the steps of this sorcery incantation/ritual/whatever are? Since everything in the universe happens by G-d's Will, this type of thinking can be extended to anything.

Comment: @user9806 But isn't what Eliyahoo did on Carmel sorcery? It surely was, but because he warned everyone that it comes from G-d it was allowed.